# when i use findby($id) with association conditions i get SQL Error: 1054

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

i use this variable to find the comments that related with articles..

```
 $comment = $this->Article->Comment->findAllById($id);
```

i get errors when i added conditons like this..

```
  $comment = $this->Article->Comment->findAllById($id,array('conditions' => array('Comment.status' => 1)));
```

i see this error>>

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Comment.' in 'field list' [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo_source.php, line 684]
Query: SELECT DISTINCT `Comment`.`` FROM `comments` AS `Comment` LEFT JOIN `articles` AS `Article` ON (`Comment`.`article_id` = `Article`.`id`) WHERE `Comment`.`id` = 15
```

Comment: Can you post your database table configuration and model please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [manual for the `findAllBy<field_name>()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findallby) method.

You'll notice the second parameter is an array of `fields`.

I would recommend using Cake's standard find method, something like:

```
$comment = $this->Article->Comment->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'Comment.id'     => $id,
    'Comment.status' => 1
  )
));
```

Comment: No worries @user1080247. Take it easy.